# Find out whether a private key is on a hardware device without the device present

Tags: .net, smartcard

I want to find out whether a certificate's private key is stored in a hardware device or not.
Let's assume the following application

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in store.Certificates)
            {
                if (x509.HasPrivateKey)
                {
                    AsymmetricAlgorithm a = x509.PrivateKey;
                    RSACryptoServiceProvider r = a as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
                    if (null != r)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("hardware: " + r.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + x509.Subject);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("container: " + r.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("---");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Information could not be written out for this certificate.");
        }
    }
}
```

The information I'm looking for is in `r.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice`.
But unfortunately for stores provided by the base smart card csp I get prompted to insert the device once `AsymmetricAlgorithm a = x509.PrivateKey` is executed (if the smardcard isn't present at that time).
Is there a way to get the same information without this annoying "please insert smartcard" dialog popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that all my smart card certificates have two properties which other certificates don't. They can be queried by calling [`CertGetCertificateContextProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `CERT_SCARD_PIN_ID_PROP_ID` or `CERT_SCARD_INFO_PROP_ID`. I don't know whether this is definitive but it works for me.

This example should list smart card certificates only:

```cs
class Program
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    extern public static bool CertGetCertificateContextProperty(IntPtr pCertContext, Int32 dwPropId, IntPtr pvData, ref Int32 pcbData);

    const int CERT_SCARD_PIN_ID_PROP_ID = 90;
    const int CERT_SCARD_INFO_PROP_ID = 91;

    static bool CertificateHasProperty(X509Certificate x509, int propId)
    {
        int cbData = 0;
        // If the property exists CertGetCertificateContextProperty returns true
        // and sets cbData to the size of buffer required to hold the data.
        return CertGetCertificateContextProperty(x509.Handle, propId, IntPtr.Zero, ref cbData);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in store.Certificates)
        {
            if (CertificateHasProperty(x509, CERT_SCARD_INFO_PROP_ID))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + x509.Subject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```